# Google Sites appending atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com to my API calls - how can I make calls using my domain only?

Tags: google-sites

I am trying to use a Web API to get some mapping data.  To enable this I have to register my domain name with the supplier, they issue me with a unique key for the domain name and then check that calls from the domain use the key.

When the API is called to return mapping data, the supplier is expecting something like:

<please-send-maps-to [www.mydomainname.com](http://www.mydomainname.com), key="whatevermykeyis">

however, I am using new Google Sites to build my website and the supplier is actually receiving something like:

<please-send-maps-to 1841824776-atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com, key="whatevermykeyis">

So my API calls are always rejected.  My domain provider tells me this is because my transactions are going through Google security layers and so translate my calls to a different domain name.

Anyway, does anyone know how I can make the API calls with my true domain name and make the API work?

Here is the embed code I use to make the api call to return the mapping details:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <title>Navionics Web API v2</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://webapiv2.navionics.com/dist/webapi/webapi.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://webapiv2.navionics.com/dist/webapi/webapi.min.no-dep.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, .test_map_div {
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body data-root="https://webapiv2.navionics.com/dist/webapi/images" >
   <div class="test_map_div" ></div>
    <script>
        var webapi = new JNC.Views.BoatingNavionicsMap({
            tagId: '.test_map_div',
            center: [  12.0, 46.0 ],
            navKey: 'Navionics_webapi_mynavkey'
        });

        webapi.showSonarControl(false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```